# Audit DB in Nestjs and Typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, psql, audit

I want to audit the DB actions of some entities in my NestJs application. Subscribers and Listeners are great features, but I am unsure which one to use and how to use it.

Some of my entities extend TimeProperty Class

```
export default class TimeProperty {
  @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp with time zone", default: "NOW()" })
  created_time: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: "timestamp with time zone",
    onUpdate: "NOW()",
    nullable: false,
  })
  updated_time: Date;
}
```

If I chose Listeners, then how can I have a common class that the entities can extend in which I can define the `@AfterInsert` hooks

If I chose Subscriber, it subscribes to actions on all entities. I want to subscribe to some entities and simultaneously would like a single Subscriber file instead of an entity-specific subscriber file.